# How to define an unsigned 64-bit integer in Delphi7?

Tags: delphi, uint64

In Delphi 7, int64s are signed, if I try to declare a hex constant larger than $8000000000000000 (eg, what is really an uint64) I get an error. Can you advise some workarounds, please?

Comment: workaround: Get a newer version of delphi that has UINT64

Comment: @Warren P, buying new version not qualifies as workaround at all.

Comment: Okay. Learn some inline assembler. :-) Import a DLL written in Visual C++ or FreePascal, or some other language...

Answer (score 6):

You can make a variant record like so

```
type muint64 = record
  case boolean of
    true: (i64 : int64);
    false:(lo32, hi32: cardinal);
end;
```

Now you can just use the cardinals to fill your uint64 with unsigned data.

The other option would be to use code like this:

```
const almostmaxint64 = $800000045000000; 
var muint64: int64;    
begin
   muint64:= almostmaxint64;
   muint64:= muint64 shl 1;
end
```

Comment: You just reinvented `Int64Rec` type, dedicated specially for that purpose. Also, should use fundamental `LongWord` type instead of generic `Cardinal`. Also, DWORDs are swapped.

Comment: @downvoter i know that's what the op asked for a workaround doesn't that mean code and not text?

Answer (score 2):

Without support from the compiler you don't have many options.

I'm presuming that you wish to pass a value to a function in some external DLL. You'll have to declare the parameter as a signed 64 bit integer, `Int64`. Then all you can do is pass in the signed value that has the same bit pattern as the desired unsigned value. Build yourself a little converter tool with a compiler that has support for unsigned 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, Broland implementations suffered interoperability issues because lack of largest **unsigned** supported by target platform. I remember using `LongInt` values instead of `DWORD` and waiting for troubles since very early days of Turbo Pascal for Windows. Then was `Cardinal` happiness, but no, D4 introduced largest integer `Int64` in its signed form only. Again.

So your only option is to rely on signed fundamental type `Int64` and pray... wait, no, just use `Int64Rec` typecast to perform arithmetics on least and most significant part **separately**.

Back to constant declaration:

```
const
  foo = $8000004200000001; // this will work because hexadecimal notation is unsigned by its nature
                           // however, declared symbol foo becomes signed Int64 value
                           // attempting to use decimal numeral will result in "Integer constant too large" error
                           // see "True constants" topic in D7 Help for more details

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // just to verify
  Caption := IntToHex(foo, SizeOf(Int64) * 2);
end;
```

Unfortunately, the other workaround is to change your compiler. Free Pascal always keeps signed and unsigned types in sync.

---

This snippet compiles and yields correct result in Borland Delphi Version 15.0 (a.k.a Delphi 7).

Comment: newer versions of delphi have UINT64 also.

Comment: No, because you didn't answer the question.

Comment: IF memory serves me right, the reason for the lack of those types was that in order to do calculations between a UInt64 and a signed type, you'd need an internal type of at least 65 bits wide. (Replace 64 with 32 and 65 with 33 for the Cardinal/LongWord case). Getting that right is a lot harder than just having the signed types.