# How to declare an Int64 constant?

Tags: delphi, constants, delphi-7, delphi-5, int64

i'm trying to define a constant in Delphi:

```
const
   FNV_offset_basis = 14695981039346656037;
```

And i get the error: **Integer constant too large**

> **Note:** `14,695,981,039,346,656,037` decimal is equal to `0x14650FB0739D0383` hex.

How can i declare this `Int64` constant?

Some other things i've tried:

```
const
   FNV_offset_basis: Int64 = 14695981039346656037;
   FNV_offset_basis = Int64(14695981039346656037);
   FNV_offset_basis: Int64 = Int64(14695981039346656037);


var
   offset: LARGE_INTEGER;
begin
   //recalculate constant every function call
   offset.LowPart = $739D0383;
   offset.HighPart = $14650FB0;
```

**Correction**

My fundamental assumption was wrong.

Pasting `14695981039346656037` into Windows 7 Calculator, and converting to hex, led me to believe that the hex equivalent of `14695981039346656037` is `0x14650FB0739D0383`:

[image]

That is incorrect.

So when i saw a 16-digit hex value, with the high bit *not set*, i presumed it could fit in a 64-bit *signed* integer.

In reality the hex equivalent of `14695981039346656037` is...something else. Rob, you were right! (probably)

Comment: Have you tried: `FNV_offset_basis = $14650FB0739D0383;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define an unsigned 64-bit integer in Delphi7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378107/how-to-define-an-unsigned-64-bit-integer-in-delphi7)

Comment: For the record: "FNV_offset_basis = 14695981039346656037" works in Delphi XE2.

Comment: @RRUZ That question is about *unsigned* 64-bit integers. This is about Delphi and its *signed* 64-bit integers. And a smarmy answer in that thread is to "buy a new version of Delphi" (*thanks*)

Comment: @RobKennedy Deleted mine as well :)

Comment: Your hex value is wrong; the number converts to decimal `1469598103934665603` (note the rightmost digits - the final `7` is missing; shifting 1 place left to add it causes an overflow).

Comment: I might have been right that your two values weren't equal, but I wasn't right about what the real value was. My calculator was showing a multiple of 1000, yet it showed the least significant bit set, and we know there's no such thing as an even number with that bit set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your hex conversion in the question is incorrect. That number is actually $cbf29ce484222000 and does not fit into a signed 64 bit integer. You would need an unsigned 64 bit integer to represent it. There is no unsigned UInt64 in Delphi 5 and so you are out of luck. There is no integral data type that can represent that number in your version of Delphi.

You could perhaps interpret the bit pattern as a signed value if that does what you need. In that case you would have a negative number.

Comment: The number is signed, and fits, signed, into an Int64.

Comment: It does not fit. It is cbf29ce484222000

Comment: You are correct. Fundamentally i only only need to store the 64-bits in a 64-bit variable long enough to perform a `mod` operation on it (but fundamentally). What is the decimal value of `$cbf29ce484222000` when assuming it is a *signed* 64-bit integer?

Comment: -$340D631B7BDDE000 or -3750763034362896384

Comment: Is there a problem with this answer? Or Jon's?

Answer (score 5):

That number is bigger than a signed 64-bit integer can hold. Have you tried using `UInt64` instead?

Comment: Delphi 5 (1999) and 7 (2002) both have `Int64`, but neither has `UInt64`. Modern Delphi versions do, however. :)

Comment: (`UInt64` in Delphi 7 exists, bud it just equals to the signed `Int64`.)

Answer (score 5):

i only needed the 64-bit variable to hold a 64-bit (unsigned) number. i can still use Delphi's `Int64` to accomplish it, but the trick was how to declare my needed constants:

```
const
    FNV_offset_basis: ULARGE_INTEGER = (LowPart: $cbf29ce4; HighPart: $84222000);
```

(thanks for Dave and Rob for finding me the *correct* hex value)

While i am, strictly speaking, not using the `Int64`, i am using an Int64:

```
var
   hash: Int64;
begin
   hash := FNV_offset_basis.QuadPart;

   for i := 1 to Length(s) do
   begin
       hash := hash xor Byte(s[i]);
       hash := UInt64Mul(hash, 1099511628211);       
   end;

   Result := UInt64mod(hash, map.Length);
end;
```

With some carefully crafted `UInt64Xxx` math routines:

```
function UInt64mod(const Dividend: Int64; const Divisor: DWORD): DWORD;
var
    d2: LongWord;
    remainder: LongWord;
begin
    //Upper half of dividend cannot be larger than divisior, or else a #de divide error occurs
    //Keep multiplying by two until it's larger.
    //We fixup at the end
    d2 := Divisor;
    while d2 < u.HighPart do
       d2 := d2 * 2;

    asm
        MOV   EDX, ULARGE_INTEGER(Dividend).HighPart;
        MOV   EAX, ULARGE_INTEGER(Dividend).LowPart;
        MOV   ECX, d2;

        //EAX := EDX:EAX / r/m32, EDX=remainder
        DIV   ECX;
        MOV   remainder,EDX
    end;

    //Fixup for using larger divisor
    Result := remainder mod Divisor;
end;
```

i'll leave the implementation `UInt64Mul` as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I had a WMI call that returned a Variant of type Uint64 not supported by Delphi 5.
By assuming that Int64 was fair enough for the result I was expecting,
1- I Typecasted and stored the returned Variant into an Extended (Real Type),
2- I used the "Trunc" function that returns an Int64 from an Extended when needed.

Not exactly what you want but considering Real Types might help someone to achieve some "impossible" Delphi 5 math.

Answer (score -1):

The Windows 7 Calculator is faulty and strips the last Digit without warning also the Calculator seems not able to really calculate in 64Bits even if QWord is selected. It seems to be a Int64 Calculator only in Windows 7 and it also can't display enough Digits and simply strips them to a totally wrong Value. Interestingly the Windows XP Calculator does not have this Bug.

And the real Hex Value of 14695981039346656037 is 0xCBF29CE484222325 also 14695981039346656037 = (20921 * 465383 * 1509404459) now as a proof try to calculate it with this Calculator and you will get -3750763034362895579 (signed) instead of 14695981039346656037 (unsigned) in Programmer Mode, but it will be correct in Scientific Mode.

Comment: @Amenom you should strive to merge your accounts. Please use the [contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)